# how to count number of records found in an array by in_array function?

Tags: php

I have an associative array $result_codes, I used in_array function to find if the provided zipcode is in array or not. Now I want to know how many zipcodes were found in array. and if there was no record then it should echo that no record found. Don't know how to do this because the loop runs before the if statement so else statement echo's message everytime when no record found in array.

```
if (bp_has_members)
while (bp_members()):
    bp_the_member()
    if ($zipcode != '')
    if (in_array($zipcode, $result_codes)) { // some code here }
        else {
            echo 'sorry, no record found';
        }
    }
    else {

        // code runs if $zipcode is empty

    }

endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: What `bp_members()` is returning? By the way are you using Wordpress Buddypress?

Comment: whats the problem to create an loop and count up the founds? Thats are basics.

Comment: using buddypress. the code is working well. I just want to display a message if no zipcode is found in array. Please focus on this part.. Code is working well.

Comment: use sizeof($result_codes) to find count of records in array

Comment: your questions (this one and the previous, related onces) doesn't fit the quality standards on this site. also you don't accept your answers (do this by clicking the accepted mark near the answer) note that nobody might help you anymore if you show such attitude

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple;
Lets say you have array

```
$array = array(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,);
```

use array_count_values($array) and you will get

```
$new_array = array(1=>3,2=>2,3=>4,4=>2,5=>4);
```

this array is a key value where the key is the value from the first array and the value is the number cells with this value;